# Failed to generate entity ui from microservie when using jdl

Tags: jhipster

I generated a microservice with jdl file using jhipster v4.6.2, when generating the gateway entity from an existing microservice, I got this error:

$ jhipster entity Media
Executing jhipster:entity Media
Options:

The entity Media is being created.

? Do you want to generate this entity from an existing microservice? Yes
? Enter the path to the microservice root directory: ../media

Found the .jhipster/Media.json configuration file, entity can be automatically generated!

Error: ERROR! 
The entity configuration file could not be read!

```
at Environment.error (/Users/austinzhang/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:140:40)
at constructor.error (/Users/austinzhang/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:1610:18)
at constructor._loadJson (/Users/austinzhang/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/entity/index.js:246:18)
at prompt.then (/Users/austinzhang/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/entity/prompts.js:87:18)
at <anonymous>
```

any ideas for resolve it.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Please post the contents of Media.json.  Did you edit it manually?